# Modify color (better, gradient) in mxGraph shapes after first rendering

Tags: mxgraph

I created a shape in mxGraph using the following options:

```
style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mxPerimeter.RectanglePerimeter;    
style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = 'black';        
style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;              
style[mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = '#2b2b2b'; 
style[mxConstants.STYLE_GRADIENTCOLOR] = 'none';
```

If I correctly understood, in case of gradient, `FILLCOLOR` becomes the *start-stop* of it, and `GRADIENTCOLOR` the *end-stop*, but it's generated via SVG at first rendering.

I'd need to create a gradient *AFTER* first rendeting, in real-time, to mimic a progress-bar (like copy files process in Windows that color icon in Application Bar).

How to add (edit) gradient color in real-time?